# Error : Terraform Azure, setting hosting mode to high density for standard3

Tags: terraform, azure-cognitive-search, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to run a script for search service setting hosting mode to high density. But I get this error: An argument named "hosting_mode" is not expected here.

```
resource "azurerm_search_service" "acc" {
  name                = "${var.cognsearch_account_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  sku                 = "standard3"
  hosting_mode        = "highDensity" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation found [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/search_service.html), hosting_mode is not a supported option.  Looking at the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/services/createorupdate) it a supported parameter.  I suggest you open an [issues](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues) with terraform-provider-azurerm.  I did see that the standard2 and standard3 skus are only available if Microsoft enables it.  Might make testing an issue.  You will have to adjust it manually, use an ARM template in terraform to update it or create the resource if updates from default -> highDensity is not allowed. (Not indicated in the documentation).

Comment: Can you show the template to write a simple search service as I have posted in the question?